# Trigger Azure Action Group from a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts

I have a Logic App running every minute that checks the time that data was last received in a table.  If it has been enough time since the data was updated I want to receive an alert.  I really like the Action Groups used by the Alerts in Azure.  They are clean and have lots of options like email, SMS, and Phone.  How can I trigger an Action Group from my Logic App?

I know I can recreate the email, SMS, and Phone connections in the Logic App, but then it's harder to maintain.  I'm already using the same Action Group for other Alerts.  It would be easier to maintain if I could reuse this Action Group.

There is ton online about triggering a Logic App from an Action Group.  This is NOT what I'm trying to do.  I want the reverse.  I want to trigger an Action Group from a Logic App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I trigger an Action Group from my Logic App?

Currently as per the documentation We can trigger a particular logic app using the action group but there is no way to trigger a particular action group using logic app.

> It would be easier to maintain if I could reuse this Action Group.

Yes, you can use same action group in multiple alert mechanisms.

Would suggest you to raise a feature request  using this [azure support](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) link.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send data to a custom log in Log Analytics from your Logic App using [Azure Log Analytics Data Collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureloganalyticsdatacollector/).

Then you can use a Log Analytics query to evaluate resources logs every set frequency, and fire an alert based on the results. Rules can trigger one or more actions using Action Groups. - see [Create, view, and manage log alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log).